process.argv get undefined in the prod build and sometimes during the dev in my electron react app
out of nowhere my process.argv are returning undefined in my react electron app and I am using electron builder
I have tried debugging and I am unable to solve it. If more context is needed please lemme know Thanks
function registerProtocol() {
    // Register your custom protocol
    if (process.defaultApp) {
        if (process.argv.length >= 2) {
            app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient(APP_PROTOCOL, process.execPath, [
                path.resolve(process.argv[1]),
            ]);
        }
    } else {
        app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient(APP_PROTOCOL);
    }

    // Handle the protocol launch
    app.on("open-url", (event, url) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        // Parse and handle the URL
        onOpenUrl(win, url);
    });

    // Handle protocol for Windows
    app.on("second-instance", (event, commandLine) => {
        const url = commandLine.find((arg) =>
            arg.startsWith(APP_PROTOCOL + "://")
        );
        if (url) onOpenUrl(win, url);
    });
}

one thing I also don't understand is that why is it entering the
(process.argv.length >= 2) { if they are undefined

if they are undefined
